# How persist data Table LocalStorage ReactJS Hooks

Tags: reactjs, datatable, local-storage

Hi guys i have a small problem with my local storage to persist my state on my table,  i would like to save the data of each cell,  for example a key which identifying one and only one cell because for the moment only the first cell is saved when i refresh the page. do you have any idea or solution plz ? this is my code thank a lot :)

this my component CellColor

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

    const COLOR = styled.div`
       td {
       width: 150px;
          }
          `;

     const CellColor = () => {
         const darkgreen = '#4FA100';
         const lightgreen = '#88FF17';
         const pink = '#FF43D7';
         const orange = '#FFA419';
         const white = '#FFFFFF';

     const [cellColor, setCellColor] = useState({
       darkgreen,
       lightgreen,
       orange,
       pink,
     });

   const handleColor = () => {
setCellColor(
  cellColor === white
    ? lightgreen
    : cellColor === lightgreen
    ? pink
    : cellColor === pink
    ? orange
    : cellColor === orange
    ? darkgreen
    : white
     );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
     const Data = localStorage.getItem('cell-data');
     setCellColor(JSON.parse(Data));
    }, []);

     useEffect(() => {
       localStorage.setItem('cell-data', JSON.stringify(cellColor));
      });

     return (
       <COLOR className="cell-color">
      <td
          className="cell-click"
           role="presentation"
           style={{ backgroundColor: cellColor }}
          onClick={(e) => handleColor(e.target.style.backgroundColor)}
        />
       </COLOR>
   );
 };

   export default CellColor;
```

so this is my table render

```
 import React, { useContext } from 'react';
 import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
 import PrevContext from '../service/PrevContext';
 import './StylePlanning.css';
 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
 import COLUMNS from './table-components/Columns';
 import DataCell from './table-components/DataCell';

 const TablePrev = () => {
    const { prevName } = useContext(PrevContext);
    const { firstname, lastname } = prevName;

     return (
<div className="block-planning-prev">
  <Table bordered style={{ color: 'navy', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
    <thead>
      <tr className="row0">
        <td className="month-title" colSpan="31">
          <input type="month" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr className="row1">
        <td>Preventeur</td>
        {COLUMNS.map((ic) => (
          <td key={ic.accessor} value={ic.Header}>
            {ic.Header}
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    {prevName.map((i) => (
      <tbody>
        <tr className="row0">
          <th
            key={i._id}
            value={(firstname, lastname)}
            className="column0"
            rowSpan="2"
          >
            {i.firstname}
            {i.lastname}
          </th>
          {DataCell.map((id) => (
            <td key={id.key} value={(id.col, id.col1)} className="column1">
              {id.col}
              {id.col1}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
        <tr className="row1">
          {DataCell.map((item) => (
            <td
              key={item.key}
              value={(item.col, item.col1)}
              className="column2"
            >
              {item.col}
              {item.col1}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    ))}
     </Table>
   </div>
   );
 };
   export default TablePrev;
```

and here my data file

```
 import React from 'react';
 import CellColor from './CellColor';
 import CellData from './CellData';

    const DATA = [
     {
      col: <CellColor />,
      col1: <CellData />,
      key: '1',
    },
    {
      col: <CellColor />,
      col1: <CellData />,
      key: '2',
    },
    {
      col: <CellColor />,
      col1: <CellData />,
      key: '3',
    },
    {
      etc.
    ]
    export default DATA;
```

Comment: can you please add your table rendering code as well?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera yes sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `key` of your `DATA` to your cell color component. Then save to local storage and retrieve using `key` like below. (Assuming `key` is unique for a cell)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const Data = localStorage.getItem(`${this.props.key}`);
        setCellColor(JSON.parse(Data));
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(`${this.props.key}`, JSON.stringify(cellColor));
    });
```

Comment: so i import my const DATA in my component, but i need a new useState to pass the props no ?

Answer (score 0):

you will rewrite data on cell-data you have to change to key to set them on localsotrage

Answer (score 0):

i try to put a timestamp Date so now i have a unique key but now my value doesnt change
its always the first value who color all the cells of my table, i think the problem its
my JSON stringify but how can read all the value ?

```
    useEffect(() => {
       const Data = localStorage.getItem(Date('key'));
       setCellColorData(JSON.parse(Data));
   }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
       localStorage.setItem(
       Date('key'),
       JSON.stringify(darkgreen, lightgreen, pink, orange)
    ); 
  });
```